# Flutter build fails on WSL2 with FileSystemException (OS Error: Cannot allocate memory, errno = 12)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, build, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I can't get my app to build on WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04), the build fails every time I `flutter run`.

```
bartek at Barteks-MSI in discover-rudy on master $ flutter run -v                                              19:53:55
[ +121 ms] executing: [/home/bartek/flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log

<-- A LOT OF UNIMPORTANT STUFF (pub get logs, etc) I CUT -->
 
[  +16 ms] Generating
/home/bartek/dev/flutter/discover-rudy/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
[  +26 ms] ro.hardware = ranchu
[  +23 ms] Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone x86 arm. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling
software
           rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
[  +23 ms] Starting incremental build...
[   +2 ms] Initializing file store
[  +15 ms] Skipping target: gen_localizations
[   +5 ms] complete
[   +4 ms] Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
[   +6 ms] /home/bartek/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart --disable-dart-dev
/home/bartek/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/linux-x64/frontend_server.dart.snapshot --sdk-root
/home/bartek/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/common/flutter_patched_sdk/ --incremental --target=flutter
--debugger-module-names --experimental-emit-debug-metadata -Ddart.developer.causal_async_stacks=true --output-dill
/tmp/flutter_tools.GKVNCF/flutter_tool.KDROCN/app.dill --packages .packages -Ddart.vm.profile=false
-Ddart.vm.product=false
--bytecode-options=source-positions,local-var-info,debugger-stops,instance-field-initializers,keep-unreachable-code,avoi
d-closure-call-instructions --enable-asserts --track-widget-creation --filesystem-scheme org-dartlang-root
--initialize-from-dill build/cache.dill.track.dill
[  +14 ms] executing: /home/bartek/androidsdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[  +66 ms] Exit code 0 from: /home/bartek/androidsdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[        ] --------- beginning of main
           10-08 19:55:36.170 E/wifi_forwarder(  410): RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to
           open pipe
[   +2 ms] executing: /home/bartek/androidsdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[  +57 ms] Exit code 0 from: /home/bartek/androidsdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[        ] --------- beginning of kernel
           10-08 19:55:48.981 D/logd    (    0): logdr: UID=2000 GID=2000 PID=25831 n tail=1 logMask=99 pid=0 start=0ns
           timeout=0ns
[  +28 ms] <- compile package:discover_rudy/main.dart
[  +23 ms] executing: /home/bartek/androidsdk/platform-tools/adb version
[  +41 ms] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
           Version 30.0.4-6686687
           Installed as /home/bartek/androidsdk/platform-tools/adb
[   +2 ms] executing: /home/bartek/androidsdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
[  +26 ms] Building APK
[  +22 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[   +3 ms] gradle.properties already sets `android.enableR8`
[   +4 ms] Using gradle from /home/bartek/dev/flutter/discover-rudy/android/gradlew.
[   +1 ms] /home/bartek/dev/flutter/discover-rudy/android/gradlew mode: 33261 rwxr-xr-x.
[   +6 ms] executing: [/home/bartek/dev/flutter/discover-rudy/android/]
/home/bartek/dev/flutter/discover-rudy/android/gradlew -Pverbose=true -Ptarget-platform=android-x86
-Ptarget=/home/bartek/dev/flutter/discover-rudy/lib/main.dart -Ptrack-widget-creation=true
-Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root assembleDebug
[ +986 ms] > Configure project :app
[   +1 ms] WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=true' is deprecated.
[        ] It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
[        ] You will no longer be able to disable R8
[+3572 ms] > Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug
[        ] [ +144 ms] executing: [/home/bartek/flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[   +1 ms] [  +57 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] [   +1 ms] d408d302e22179d598f467e11da5dd968dbdc9ec
[        ] [   +1 ms] executing: [/home/bartek/flutter/] git tag --points-at HEAD
[        ] [  +33 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --points-at HEAD
[        ] [   +1 ms] 1.22.0
[        ]            1.22.0-12.3.pre
[        ] [  +16 ms] executing: [/home/bartek/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] [  +21 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] [        ] origin/stable
[        ] [        ] executing: [/home/bartek/flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] [  +20 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] [        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[        ] [ +117 ms] executing: [/home/bartek/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] [  +25 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] [   +1 ms] stable
[        ] [  +46 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [  +16 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MaterialFonts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'GradleWrapper' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FontSubsetArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [  +98 ms] Initializing file store
[        ] [  +22 ms] Done initializing file store
[        ] [  +56 ms] Skipping target: gen_localizations
[  +83 ms] [+1032 ms] Skipping target: kernel_snapshot
[        ] [   +6 ms] debug_android_application: Starting due to {}
[ +605 ms] [ +567 ms] Manifest contained wildcard assets. Inserting missing file into build graph to force rerun. for
more information see #56466.
[        ] [  +60 ms] Persisting file store
[        ] [  +16 ms] Done persisting file store
[  +94 ms] [  +12 ms] Target debug_android_application failed: FileSystemException: Cannot copy file to
'/home/bartek/dev/flutter/discover-rudy/build/app/intermediates/flutter/debug/flutter_assets/assets/gmina_kuznia.jpg',
path = '/home/bartek/dev/flutter/discover-rudy/assets/gmina_kuznia.jpg' (OS Error: Cannot allocate memory, errno = 12)
[   +2 ms]            #0      _File.copy.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:328:9)
[        ]            #1      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
[        ]            #2      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
[        ]            #3      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
[        ]            #4      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
[        ]            #5      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
[        ]            #6      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
[        ]            #7      Future._asyncCompleteWithValue.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:567:7)
[        ]            #8      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
[        ]            #9      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
[        ]            #10     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
[        ]            #11     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
[        ]            #12     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
[        ]            #13     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
[        ]            #14     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
[        ]            #15     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)
[        ] [   +3 ms]
[        ]            #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:14:3)
[        ]            #1      AssembleCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/assemble.dart:238:7)
[        ]            #2      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
[        ]            #3      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
[        ]            #4      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
[        ]            #5      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
[        ]            #6      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
[        ]            #7      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
[        ]            #8      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15)
[        ]            #9      _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13)
[        ]            #10     FlutterBuildSystem.build (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart)
[        ]            #11     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
[        ]            #12     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
[        ]            #13     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
[        ]            #14     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
[        ]            #15     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
[        ]            #16     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
[        ]            #17     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15)
[        ]            #18     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13)
[        ]            #19     _BuildInstance._invokeInternal (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart)
[        ]            #20     _asyncErrorWrapperHelper.errorCallback (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:91:64)
[        ]            #21     _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1214:47)
[        ]            #22     _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1107:19)
[        ]            #23     _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:157:20)
[        ]            #24     Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:708:47)
[        ]            #25     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:729:24)
[        ]            #26     Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:537:5)
[        ]            #27     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:47:15)
[        ]            #28     AndroidAssetBundle.build (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/targets/android.dart)
[        ]            #29     _asyncErrorWrapperHelper.errorCallback (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:91:64)
[        ]            #30     _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1214:47)
[        ]            #31     _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1107:19)
[        ]            #32     _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:157:20)
[        ]            #33     Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:708:47)
[        ]            #34     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:729:24)
[        ]            #35     Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:537:5)
[        ]            #36     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:47:15)
[        ]            #37     copyAssets (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/targets/assets.dart)
[        ]            #38     _asyncErrorWrapperHelper.errorCallback (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:91:64)
[        ]            #39     _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1214:47)
[        ]            #40     _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1107:19)
[        ]            #41     _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:157:20)
[        ]            #42     Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:708:47)
[        ]            #43     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:729:24)
[        ]            #44     Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:537:5)
[        ]            #45     Future.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:426:23)
[        ]            #46     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
[        ]            #47     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
[        ]            #48     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
[        ]            #49     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
[        ]            #50     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
[        ]            #51     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
[        ]            #52     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15)
[        ]            #53     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13)
[        ]            #54     copyAssets.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/targets/assets.dart)
[        ]            #55     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
[        ]            #56     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
[        ]            #57     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
[        ]            #58     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
[        ]            #59     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
[        ]            #60     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
[        ]            #61     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15)
[   +2 ms]            #62     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13)
[        ]            #63     ForwardingFile.copy (package:file/src/forwarding/forwarding_file.dart)
[        ]            #64     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
[        ]            #65     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
[        ]            #66     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
[        ]            #67     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
[        ]            #68     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
[        ]            #69     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
[        ]            #70     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15)
[        ]            #71     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13)
[        ]            #72     ForwardingFile.copy (package:file/src/forwarding/forwarding_file.dart)
[        ]            #73     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
[        ]            #74     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
[        ]            #75     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
[        ]            #76     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
[        ]            #77     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
[        ]            #78     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
[        ]            #79     Future._asyncCompleteWithValue.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:567:7)
[        ]            #80     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
[        ]            #81     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
[        ]            #82     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
[        ]            #83     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
[        ]            #84     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
[        ]            #85     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
[        ]            #86     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
[        ]            #87     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)
[   +1 ms] [  +19 ms] "flutter assemble" took 1,917ms.
[        ] [   +2 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 0ms
[        ] [   +1 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] [        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] [   +3 ms] exiting with code 1
[ +168 ms] > Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug FAILED
[        ] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[        ] * Where:
[        ] Script '/home/bartek/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 904
[        ] * What went wrong:
[        ] Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
[        ] > Process 'command '/home/bartek/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
[        ] * Try:
[        ] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log
output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[        ] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[        ] BUILD FAILED in 5s
[        ] Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
[        ] Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
[        ] See https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[        ] 1 actionable task: 1 executed
[ +495 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 6.1s)
[+3873 ms] Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
[   +1 ms] "flutter run" took 11,230ms.
[   +4 ms]
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:14:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:607:7)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:972:18)
           #3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #5      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #7      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #8      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #9      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15)
           #10     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13)
           #11     RunCommand.usageValues (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart)
           #12     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #13     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #14     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #15     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #16     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #17     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #18     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15)
           #19     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13)
           #20     AndroidDevice.isLocalEmulator (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart)
           #21     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #22     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #23     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #24     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #25     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #26     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #27     Future._asyncCompleteWithValue.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:567:7)
           #28     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
           #29     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
           #30     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
           #31     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
           #32     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
           #33     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
           #34     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
           #35     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)


[ +175 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 170ms
[        ] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hook priority 4
[   +3 ms] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] exiting with code 1
```

[full logs here](https://gist.github.com/bartekpacia/6c8aed72b35aee95ab06257167132305)

I think it might be something with filesystem permissions because I for sure have enough memory?

Here's `flutter doctor`:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.0, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.22.0 at /home/bartek/flutter
    • Framework revision d408d302e2 (9 days ago), 2020-09-29 11:49:17 -0700
    • Engine revision 5babba6c4d
    • Dart version 2.10.0


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/bartek/androidsdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = /home/bartek/androidsdk
    • Java binary at: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_265-8u265-b01-0ubuntu2~20.04-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • sdk gphone x86 arm (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error on WSL1 and it looks like a Dart runtime bug (not confirmed). I don't have a real solution but here is how I worked around:

1. Go to your Flutter installation directory.
2. Modify `packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/build_system/targets/assets.dart` as follows (convert `Future.wait(Iterable<Future>)` into a plain for loop):

   ```
   diff --git a/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/build_system/targets/assets.dart b/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/build_system/targets/assets.dart
   index 83684e4455..b0bb340a79 100644
   --- a/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/build_system/targets/assets.dart
   +++ b/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/build_system/targets/assets.dart
   @@ -86,8 +86,7 @@ Future<Depfile> copyAssets(Environment environment, Directory outputDirectory, {
         kSkSLShaderBundlePath: skslBundle,
      };

   -  await Future.wait<void>(
   -    assetEntries.entries.map<Future<void>>((MapEntry<String, DevFSContent> entry) async {
   +  for (final MapEntry<String, DevFSContent> entry in assetEntries.entries) {
         final PoolResource resource = await pool.request();
         try {
            // This will result in strange looking files, for example files with `/`
   @@ -115,7 +114,7 @@ Future<Depfile> copyAssets(Environment environment, Directory outputDirectory, {
         } finally {
            resource.release();
         }
   -  }));
   +  }

      // Copy deferred components assets only for release or profile builds.
      // The assets are included in assetBundle.entries as a normal asset when
   ```
3. Remove `bin/cache/flutter_tools.snapshot` to [force the Flutter Tools snapshot to be re-generated](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/packages/flutter_tools#forcing-snapshot-regeneration).
4. Try `flutter build` or `flutter run` again.